# Cron Execution Issue

Tags: cron, awk

First off, I have searched past crontab related postings without finding any pointer to what the problem I'm having might be, so apologies if this has already been covered. Also, sorry if the following is too verbose.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4

I have created a script (inetavail.sh) that I want to kick off on a minute basis to determine if my ISP is having service gaps (I've been on numerous Zoom calls lately and have been kicked out due to lost internet).  Below is the content of my script (which uses hping3):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sample Output:
# 06/26/2020, 13:15, Online
# or
# 06/26/2020, 13:15, Offline

dt=`date +'%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M'`

err=$(hping3 www.google.com -c 1 -S -p 80 2>&1 >/dev/null)

echo $err|awk -v dt="$dt" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/%/)print ($i=="100%")? dt", Offline" : dt", Online"}'

exit
```

My crontab entry looks as follows:

```
* * * * * /home/lava/.util/inetavail/inetavail.sh >> /home/lava/.util/inetavail/inetavail.csv
```

Once I have the output file (csv) I have another script that generates a gnuplot graph (when called) to give a graphical representation of gaps in internet service.

Executing the script (/home/lava/.util/inetavail/inetavail.sh >> /home/lava/.util/inetavail/inetavail.csv) from the command-line is successful, but when executing it via cron, I don't get any output.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? In order to be able to execute hping3 as myself (non-root), I had to execute the following command following the installation of hping3:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/sbin/hping3
```

Is it possible that hping3, when executed from cron is failing to execute (with open_sockraw operation permission)? I've tried to run the same script as root cron, without success.

Thanks for suggestions.

Tex

Comment: As an usual mistake, cron does not load execution context (path var). you must call all program files will full path IE `/usr/bin/date`, `/usr/sbin/hping3` and `/usr/bin/awk`

Comment: There should be no problem with `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, but `/usr/sbin` is indeed not in cron's PATH by default (you can check by adding a cron job that runs `printenv`)

Comment: Putting /usr/sbin/hping3 did the trickm Thanks for your help!